# Sitecore tasks configuration from web.config

Tags: scheduled-tasks, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to configure a task to run every 5 seconds (in production the fequency will be set to 30 minutes, but i set it to 5 seconds for debugging).

```
<scheduling>
  <!-- Time between checking for scheduled tasks waiting to execute -->
  <frequency>00:00:10</frequency>
....
<agent type="MyStuff.Sitecore.Tasks.UpdateJob" method="Run" interval="00:00:05">
        <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
      </agent>
```

my class looks like:

```
namespace MyStuff.Sitecore.Tasks
{
    public class UpdateJob
    {
       public void Run()
       {
          //debugger never enters here
       }
    }
}
```

But no matter what, the code never seems to be invoked. I've tried hitting other webpages so i know the asp.net worker process is alive.

the class is in a shared library which is invoked in the web site project, so whatever sitecore configuration is looking for the `MyStuff.Sitecore.Tasks.UpdateJob` type should be able to find it. Also, i've checked in the Sitecore logs and i don't see any error or anything regarding the task

any idea what i'm missing?

---

**Edit** the only thing "suspicious" that i'm seeing in the logs is:

```
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:53:10 INFO  Starting update of index for the database 'master' (1 pending).
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:53:10 INFO  Update of index for the database 'master' done.
ManagedPoolThread #18 15:53:36 ERROR Exception in geoip worker thread.
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object[] args, SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetProviders[TProvider,TCollection](List`1 nodes)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetProviders[TProvider,TCollection](String rootPath, TProvider& defaultProvider)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.ReadProviders()
   at Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.get_Provider()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpWorker.ProcessGeoIp()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpWorker.<Wakeup>b__3(Object a)
```

I'm using Sitecore 6.5

Answer (score 3):

Can you try updating your agent declaration to `<agent type="Mystuff.Sitecore.Tasks.UpdateJob, Mystuff" method="Run" interval="00:00:05">` where the Mystuff is your assembly name. Seems like the assembly is missing.

*Added as answer based on techphoria414's suggestion.*

Comment: and remember that Sitecore Scheduled Task will start just in case you have a call to you website !

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm side-stepping your question a bit, I have never been successful with getting the debugger to be called while working on scheduled tasks.  I instead used `Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log` and then the related debug level I'm looking to display. Often times I found this rather limiting, but with a third-party tail utility you can watch the log rather easily as it happens.

Maybe this will give you an interm solution until someone else answers.

Comment: nothing that i'm logging on the job itself is in the log. The log is logging for stuff being processed on normal web request so i presume that the task is just not running

Comment: Can you try updating your agent declaration to `<agent type="Mystuff.Sitecore.Tasks.UpdateJob, Mystuff" method="Run" interval="00:00:05">` where the Mystuff is your assembly name. Shot in the dark but as no one else has chimed in.

Comment: You should post that comment as your answer because my money would be on that.

Comment: @al3xnull : Your comment is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in `<frequency>00:00:10</frequency>`, this should always be as low as your most frequent task, so in this case 00:00:05.